# extpython version compatible,generator attributeError _next_ when using tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data,dropout,fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d,max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17
x,y=oxflower17.load_data(one_hot=True,resize_pics=(227,227))

network = inputdata(shape=[None,227,227,3])
network = conv_2d(network,96,11,strides=4,activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network,3,strides=2)
network = local_response_normalization(network)
network = conv_2d(network,256,5,activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network,3,strides=2)
network = loca_response_normalization(network)
network = conv_2d(network,384,3,activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network,384,3,activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network,256,activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network,3,strides=2)
network = local_response_normalization(network)
network = fully_connected(network,4096,activation='tanh')
network = dropout(network,0.5)
network = fully_connected(network,4096,activation='tanh')
network = dropout(network,0.5)
network = fully_connected(network,17,activation='softmax')
network =regression(network,optimizer='momentum',loss='categorical_crossentropy',learning_rate=0.001)
```

and I am using python 2.7 with jupyter notebook and tensorflow 1.0

when I perform the code
 it shows

737         classes = sorted(os.walk(directory).next()[1])

738     except Exception: # Python 3

739         classes = sorted(os.walk(directory).**next**()[1])

```
740     for c in classes:

741         c_dir = os.path.join(directory, c)
```

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '**next**'